# Why aren't all fatal errors catchable in PHP 7?

Tags: php, exception, fatal-error

Going from PHP 5 to PHP 7, a syntax error is no longer a fatal error but a `Throwable` exception that can be caught. However, some fatal errors, like "Class not found" are still fatal in PHP 7. Why weren't all fatal errors converted to `Throwable`?

Example:

```
try {
  include "file_with_syntax_error.php";
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
  // Do something
}
```

But

```
try {
  include "file_with_namespace_error.php";
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
  // Won't work
}
```

**Edit**: There's a comment from the bug report https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72089:

> Generally, that has already been done for PHP 7.0.0 where
>   reasonable and possible, see
>   https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7.

Comment: I think there is no clear answer for this, so I'm voting it to close as opinion based. Keep in mind you can always do a `file_exists()` or  other methods to check validity and throw a `Throwable` or `Error` manually.

Comment: There's an open PHP bug around a similar issue here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72089 (specifically, the comment from last year regarding the missing Interface). In short, not all fatal errors currently produce a `Throwable`, and hence can't be caught. As far as I can tell, it's down to issues with the engine, rather than a specific design decision.

Comment: @Xorifelse Well, the developer who implemented the ParseError etc would probably know the answer. :)

Comment: For this particular case, the reason is that require/include errors are not generated directly and instead go, for whatever reason, through a "zend message dispatcher" mechanism. This hasn't been converted to throw yet.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question, you are not talking about the "file not found" fatal error here, but something else. If this is referring to compiler errors in general, then the reason is basically that this would require threading error handling through the entire compiler. Additionally some parts of compilation (such as early binding) have visible consequences, which would have to be undone or delayed. It's a lot of work for questionable benefit.